# Webpack 4 - Module not found: Can't resolve node_modules

Tags: node.js, express, webpack-4

I am trying to bundle my nodejs express app with Webpack, I keep on getting the same error, will greatly appreciate help

node version **8.9.1**

webpack version **4.41.2**

Operating System **Windows 10**

My project structure

```
.
├── node_modules
├── package.json
├── README.md
├── src
│   ├── components
│   ├── index.js
|__ webpack-config.js
|
```

My Webpack config is following

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
import path from "path";
import nodeExternals from "webpack-node-externals";
module.exports = {

    entry: {app:"./src/index.js"},
    target: "node",
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'webpack-build'),
        filename: "bundle.js"
    },
    module:{
        rules:[{
            test: /\.(js)$/,
            exclude: /(node_modules)/,
            // flags to apply these rules, even if they are overridden (advanced option)
            loader: "babel-loader",
            // the loader which should be applied, it'll be resolved relative to the context
            options: {
                presets: ["es2015"]
            },
        }]
    },
    externals: [nodeExternals()]
};
```

**Things I Have Tried**

1. add webpack-node-externals to Externals property
2. Tried adding

   resolve: {
         root: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'), path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules')],
         extensions: ['', '.js']
   };

**ERROR I GET**

[image]

Comment: The main error is "Can't resolve './appmetrics'" which seems to be because [*native appmetrics module can't be found. It has possibly failed to build during the npm install phase.*](https://github.com/RuntimeTools/appmetrics/issues/539#issuecomment-418051354). Have you had any errors during installation? Do you have [nodegyp](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp) installed and working correctly?

Comment: @laggingreflex Yes, If i run the application and open appmetrics dashboard it is appearing with requests stats. The list goes on and on for all the modules I Have this is just example